# Do all sql DataSources load in asp.net Multiview control?

Tags: asp.net, .net, view, sqldatasource, multiview

**Scenario:**
We have an asp.net page with a MultiView control on it. In the MV there are 4 views, each with its own sqlDataSource or sets thereof.

**So lets say this:**
View 1:
- DataSource1
View 2:
- DataSource2
- DataSource3
View 3:
- DataSource4
- DataSource5
- DataSource6
View 4:
- DataSource7

**My question:**
If the page loads with View 1 as the active view. Do all 7 datasources attempt to execute their queries or only the ones located in "view 1"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, all those datasources will be executed hence it's not a good approach. MultiView renders only active view, but all controls in all views are going through the page life cycle therefore will be executed.